# Analytic Solution for $x^2 - x \ln x -k = 0$ ??

Tags: logarithms

Looking for the analytic solution of  $x^2 - x \ln x -k = 0$ for $x$. Have tried symbolic solver in MATLAB but couldn't find a closed-form expression. Here $0 < k < 1$.

Comment: A suggestion:  Please don't use comment space when you can instead include your addendum in the original posting.  (You can do that now!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find an analytical solution and you will need numerical methods.

Consider that you look for the zero(s) of function 
$$f(x)=x^2 - x \log(x) -k $$
$$f'(x)=2 x-\log (x)-1$$
$$f''(x)=2-\frac{1}{x}$$

The first derivative cancels at a point
$$x_*=-\frac{1}{2} W\left(-\frac{2}{e}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function. But this is not a real value since, in the real domain, this function is "defined" if $x \geq -\frac 1e$ and then the first derivative is always positive.

Since the function is bounded by $g(x)=x^2-k$, you could start Newton method with $x_0=\sqrt k$ (except for $k=1$ for which $x=1$ is the solution) and generate iterates according to
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-x_n \log (x_n)-k}{2 x_n-\log (x_n)-1}$$ and this would converge quite fast as shown below for  $k=\frac12$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.7071067812 \\
 1 & 0.3849870727 \\
 2 & 0.3633137719 \\
 3 & 0.3635195741 \\
 4 & 0.3635195956
\end{array}
\right)$$ You could generate a better estimate assuming that $x^2-x\log(x)\approx x^a$ and get $a$ minimizing
$$\Phi(a)=\int_0^1 \left(x^2-x\log(x)- x^a \right)^2\,dx=\frac{1}{2 a+1}-\frac{2}{(a+2)^2}-\frac{2}{a+3}+\frac{431}{1080}$$
$$\frac{d\Phi(a)}{da}=-\frac{2}{(2 a+1)^2}+\frac{4}{(a+2)^3}+\frac{2}{(a+3)^2}=0 \implies a\approx 0.7\implies x_0=k^{10/7}$$ Surprisingly, the optimal value of $a=0.692477$ is very close to $\log(2)$.

For the worked example, this would give $x_0=0.3715$ and Newton method will converge quite fast.